# implementing a simple geofence in objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, algorithm, geolocation

I am trying to implement somewhat of a simple geofence algorithm that basically does the following:

> 1. Say I have two point A and B (each point has a latitude and longitude
>      value in earth).
> 2. I can draw a straight line from point A to point B
> 3. I can set a perimeter, which is a rectangle, around that line (see drawing
>      below for more clarity)

[image]

What I want to do is as follows, if the phone current location is outside of this red perimeter then it triggers something, basically a delegate. The perimeter size should be able to be adjusted to a percentage size, so 5% would be a small perimeter around the line and 70% would be a large perimeter around the line. Be aware that the perimeter should be a rectangle, not circle with radius. I am guessing that there will be a bunch of if statements involved in building this... if anyone could come up with a simple and elegant solution to this (would be great if I can see code in objective-C) that would be awesome. Or any guidance would be helpful as well

Comment: Are you doing this simplistically? i.e just treating the latitude and longitude as x,y coordinates?  Or are you doing it properly i.e. converting the lat and long to three dimensional coordinates and calculating the great circle for the straight line?

Comment: I am guessing that converting it to a 3d coordinate would make it better right? So if that is possible to integrate it to this idea then i'd like to see that

Comment: Yes, it would be better but I suspect that the geometry would be really difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a path from the four points of the rectangle and then use `CGPathContainsPoint` to check whether the current location is inside the path.

As for the conversion of latitude and longitude to planar x, y coordinates, the simplest solution is to use Mercator projection using Map Kit. Check [Understanding Map Geometry](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH3-SW5) for more info.

Here's an example:

```
// create four rectangle points from A, B
dx = (B.x - A.x) * 0.05; // 5% of the A-B length
dy = (B.y - A.y) * 0.05;

// topmost corner, above B
points[0].x = B.x + dx - dy;
points[0].y = B.y + dy + dx;

//rightmost corner, to the right from B
points[1].x = B.x + dx + dy;
points[1].y = B.y + dy - dx;

...


CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable(); 

CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, points[0].x, points[0].y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, points[1].x, points[1].y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, points[2].x, points[2].y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, points[3].x, points[3].y);

CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

// convert latitude, longitude to planar coordinates
MKMapPoint location = MKMapPointForCoordinate([newLocation coordinate]);

BOOL inside = CGPathContainsPoint(path, NULL, CGPointMake(location.x, location.y), YES);

CGPathRelease(path);
```

Note: This code expects that the current location is a point, while in reality, it is a point and a radius of accuracy, which is effectively a circle. This complicates things a bit because now you need to define how to handle situations when the current location is not known *exactly*, but you only know that it's somewhere in the circle. If the rectangle is large (say 5 km), then you may simply require radius of accuracy less than 50m, do the calculation as if the current location was exact and ignore the small inaccuracy of the computation. If the rectangle is smaller (say 50m), you may also do the calculation as if the current location was exact, but then the false positives probability would be higher (e.g. sometimes you would be detected as in the rectangle while you would be standing outside of it).

Or you may want to go for the "perfect" solution and do circle-rectangle intersection, which is more complex and may result not only in YES and NO answers but also in "with this accuracy it cannot be determined whether you are inside or outside of the rectangle".

Comment: Anyway to integrate the radius i got as well to this calculation?

Comment: How does the iphone gives you back the range of the radius using significantLocationChanges? Is it just a random variable?

Comment: This assumes the line is horizontal.... this will not work as per your original post.... Plus the original post mentions latitude and longitude which is also overlooked...

Comment: This is overly complex for the question and doesn't work if the line is not orientated correctly. My solution where you find the shortest point from your location and calculate a threshold distance is simpler and more accurate (as it is resilient to rotation).

Comment: @Simon This solution doesn't assume that the line is horizontal, it works perfectly with any line orientation.

Comment: @Simon Whether this solution is overly complex depends on the problem. Point-to-line distance is indeed simpler than this, but only if point-to-line distance is what you need (which is perfectly possible). In this case, point-to-line distance will have problems in the corners of the rectangle, in its simplest form it works for rectangles with rounded corners. Anyway, I don't think the answer is wrong (as in should-be-downvoted-wrong).

Comment: @EquinoX You should be able to get accuracy radius as newLocation.horizontalAccuracy in locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation

Comment: I don't think this should be downvoted.. it has some logic built into it. I've up voted it again.. also where did you use this horizontal accuracy at during the calculation?

Comment: @EquinoX Horizontal accuracy is not used in this calculation, it's just the simplest calculation that expects perfect accuracy.

Comment: could you also post your previous code before this, the simpler approach of just using lat and long?

Comment: I just realized that this won't work for a vertical line as the difference between the x of two points in a vertical line is 0 and therefore there won't be any rectangle around that line

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the nearest point on the main A-B line to the users location. Look at the following link for more information... [Point Line](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointline/)

Now given that you can find the nearest point on a line from users point (current location) you can check if the distance between their location and the nearest point is within the threshold you are interested in, if it exceeds it then they are 'outside' of the zone around the line.

Comment: Interesting, I actually learned that formula at high school... A lot of math and calculation involved in it, but I'll consider it anyways

Comment: Did you look at the link? That gives you the point at the tangent to the line, then use the following to get the distance.... http://www.maths.abdn.ac.uk/~igc/tch/ma1002/revision/node9.html

Comment: The math is quite simple (strangely!) :)